# Passing a pointer from a function to another function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am looking for a way to pass a pointer from *not* main function to another function. A variable x with value 5 sends as pointer to func1, func1 changes variable value to 10, then func1 sends same variable to func2.

I want it to look something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1(int *px);
void func2();

int main(void)

{   
    int x=5;
    printf("x in main %d\n", x);
    func1(&x);

    return 0;
}

void func1(int *px)
{
    *px = 10;
    printf("x i funk 1 %d\n", *px);
    funk2(); // send to this function a pointer to x, which in this function(func1) is pointed by *px
    funk3();
}

void func2()
{
    //*px=15 // here I want to change value of x 
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem with this task?

Comment: I am completely lost in how to do that.

Comment: Thank you all, that was easier than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am completely lost in how to do that.

Using the exact same logic you used for passing the pointer to `x` from `main` to `func1`.

In this case `func2` should also accept a pointer to `int`and `func1` should pass the pointer to `func2` that it got from `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1(int *px);
void func2(int *px);

int main(void)

{   
    int x=5;
    printf("x in main %d\n", x);
    func1(&x);

    // x will be 15 here

    return 0;
}

void func1(int *px)
{
    *px = 10;
    printf("x i funk 1 %d\n", *px);
    funk2(px); // send to this function a pointer to x, which in this function(func1) is pointed by *px
    //funk3(); // this function was not defined anywhere
}

void func2(int *px)
{
    *px=15;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the argument in `func1()` to `func2()`, as a pointer, `px` in `func1()` and `py` in `func2()` will point to the same memory location, the address of `x`.

```
int main(void)

{
    int x = 5;
    printf("x in main %d\n", x);
    func1(&x);

    printf("x now %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}

void func2(int *py)
{
    *py = 15; // here I want to change value of x 
}



void func1(int *px)
{
    *px = 10;
    printf("x in funk 1 %d\n", *px);
    func2(px); // send to this function a pointer to x, which in this function(func1) is pointed by *px

}
```

output:

```
x in main 5
x in funk 1 10
x now 15
```